# Magento 2.3.2 Update.log file so big

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I'm running a Magento 2.3.2 I noticed that the update.log file in the var folder grows rapidly to over 70GB 
as per the below pic 
https://i.ibb.co/1K07SHw/2019-12-17-010144.jpg

Comment: Have you checked any of the answers here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/156962/magento-2-update-log-increases-significant-size-every-minute

Comment: There you can find more information: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/156962/magento-2-update-log-increases-significant-size-every-minute

Comment: where is the answer in this post

Comment: so what you want with log file?

Answer (score 0):

looks like a permission problem for the Magento cron job.
In the log file, you will find that some paths are not writable
(`Cron readiness check failure! Found non-writable paths:`)
. Cronjob runs every Minute for that reason it grooves fast.

More Information about Permission you can find at:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/prod/prod_file-sys-perms.html

best regards,

Lars